# Host amazon lex chatbot as desktop application

Tags: user-interface, amazon-lex

I have created a Amazon lex chatbot for raising a ticket in my organisation .Now, I want to host it as desktop application.Is it possible to host lex chatbot as a stand-alone application?If so,can I get any links related to that?I am unable to get any related links for hosting lex as stand-alone application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **CAN** build your own front-end chat application and pass inputs and outputs between Lex and the user yourself using [PostText](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostText.html) or [PostContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_runtime_PostContent.html). You would also have to parse the Lex response JSON into a user friendly output as well.

You **CANNOT**, however, if you are trying to "host" your entire Lex bot within your application so that it can be used offline. Your Lex bot is only accessible through AWS servers.

Comment: I dont want to use it in offline mode.I want to host it as .exe application so that any one can download that .exe and use it

Comment: Lex does not have a simple option for that if that is what you are looking for. You can do that but you'll have to build it from scratch and then use Lex API that I linked to for passing messages between your bot and your user.